# when using the arrow keys my image disappears

Tags: java, animation, applet, keyboard, awt

The problem is that when I press the down button, the image (blueboy) disappears, and it also doesn't move up but it can move side to side, I cant understand why? please help. 
(I'm using RealJ). 
If there is a website that can help me on 2d side scrolling games that would help me as well.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.*;     
import java.awt.*;  
public class projectblue extends Applet implements     ActionListener,KeyListener,MouseListener {

Image blueboy,trees;    //image variable
int size = 4,jump = 50, cx = 1, cy = 1;    

public void init() {

   blueboy = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"png.png"); 
   trees=     getImage(getDocumentBase(),"background.jpg");
addKeyListener( this ); 
addMouseListener( this );
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{   
  int width = trees.getWidth(this);     
  int height = trees.getHeight(this);   
  //System.out.println("" + cx +","+ cy);   

  //The later images are drawn on top of the earlier ones.
  g.drawImage(trees, 1 ,1, width*size,height*7,this);
  g.drawImage(blueboy, cx, cy, this);
}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 repaint();

}
 public void left(){
      cx = cx -100;
      // blueboy moves left
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
 System.out.println("key pressed");
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        left();
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        cx = cx + 100;
        //blueboy moves right
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        while (cy >= 0 && cy <=1000)
        cy = cy - 100;
            if (cy < 0){
                cy = 1;
               //blueboy moves up, but if it goes out of bounds it goes back to the top
               }
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
       while (cy >= 0 && cy <=1000)
        cy = cy + 100;
            if (cy > 1001){
                cy = 999;
               }
        //blueboy moves down, but if it goes out of bounds it goes back to the bottim
    }
    repaint();
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e ) { } 
public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e ) { }
 public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ) { }
  public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e ) { }
   public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ) {
   int x = getX();
   int y = getY();
System.out.println("clicked at (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
} }
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec by your instructor, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT components rather than Swing?  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon AWT.

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Use a logical & consistent code formatting style!  The code indentation is intended to help people follow the program flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those while loops will tie up your GUI thread, rendering your animation useless. Shouldn't they be if blocks instead? Also, you should enclose **all** blocks in curly braces. Your indentation is lying to you, and the braces will show you why.

Also you will need to call your `super.paint(g)` method in your paint override.

Also, is this an assignment, and if so are you required to code with AWT/Applets and not Swing?

Comment: swing is not taught in our class. is there an advantage from knowing swing?

Comment: @EdwardBezzant: Ah. Consider suggesting to your instructors to move on up to the 1990's, because that is when AWT became out of date.

Comment: @EdwardBezzant: yep. If you hover your mouse over the Swing tag here: [tag:swing], click on the info link for links to great sites and resources. Here's a more direct link: [Swing Resources](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).